# Is there a way to convert a text list with /n (new line) to a string list for Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have a *file* that has a list of strings, separated by a new line.

```
10.0.0.0
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
```

I would like to convert them into a List of type String, so that I can utilize them within my Terraform.

Is there a way to do this?

I can save the file as whatever format I like.  I have been trying to save it as a yaml, then utilize `yamldecode` to make this convertion to `['10.0.0.0', '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2']` but so far, I haven't been able to.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
locals {
  lines = [for line in split("\n", file("file.txt")): chomp(line)]
}
```

This will split the input based on newline (`\n`) characters. [`chomp`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/chomp) will remove `\r` characters  in case your file is using `CLRF` endings (if you are using Windows).

Comment: Follow-up: To remove empty lines (e.g. the last one, if any), wrap the above expression with [`compact()`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/compact), i.e. `compact([for line in split("\n", file("file.txt")): chomp(line)])`.